# Failed to load URL when using ABCpdf on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, abcpdf

I'm using [ABCpdf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ABCpdf/) to generate a PDF from HTML.

```
int id = theDoc.AddImageHtml(html);
```

It's working fine in my local environment but throws an error when running on an Azure server.

Exception:

> Failed to load URL data:text/html;charset=UTF-8;base64,........

What does the error mean and how do I fix this?

Comment: By "Azure server", do you mean a virtual machine?

Comment: not virtual machine its azure server paid subscription

Comment: im getting my whole html in base 64 string in exception as Failed to load URL data:text/html;charset=UTF-8;base64,....my html in base64 string